# How to get string response values while JSON parsing in swift

Tags: json, swift, string, parsing

I am getting response like this in postman from backend

```
"{\"errorCode\":0,\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"User Undertaking\",\"utID\":\"f6W1XDIzD2lmNL81kR/D2Q==\",\"showUserUndertaking\":true,\"htmlDecription\":\"\\u003cp class=\\u0022s1\\u0022 style=\\u0022margin: 0pt; padding: 0px 0px 0px 2pt; text-indent: 0pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; text-decoration-line: underline; font-size: 20pt; line-height: 24pt; text-align: center;\\u0022\\u003e\\u003cspan style=\\u0022font-family: \\u0026quot;Times New Roman\\u0026quot;; background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);\\u0022\\u003ePARENT/STUDENT ACKNOWLEDGEMENT FORM\\u003c/span\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp style=\\u0022margin: 0pt; padding: 5pt 0px 0px; text-indent: 0pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 13pt;\\u0022\\u003e\\u003cbr style=\\u0022margin: 0px; padding: 0px;\\u0022\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp style=\\u0022margin: 0pt; padding: 0px 0px 0px 9pt; text-indent: 0pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 13pt;\\u0022\\u003e\\u003ca href=\\u0022http://www.christinak12.org/StudentManual\\u0022 target=\\u0022_blank\\u0022 style=\\u0022margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: black; font-size: 13pt;\\u0022\\u003e\\u003cu\\u003eChristina School District\\u0027\\u003c/u\\u003es \\u0022Student Manual: Responsibilities, Expectations, Rights \\u0026amp; Resources\\u0022 is available online on the District\\u0027s website at\\u0026nbsp;\\u003c/a\\u003e\\u003ca href=\\u0022http://www.christinak12.org/StudentManual\\u0022 target=\\u0022_blank\\u0022 style=\\u0022margin: 0px; padding: 0px; color: black; text-decoration-line: underline; font-size: 13pt;\\u0022\\u003ewww.christinak12.org/StudentManual\\u003c/a\\u003e\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp style=\\u0022margin: 0pt; padding: 14pt 0px 0px 9pt; text-indent: 0pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 13pt; text-align: justify;\\u0022\\u003ePlease review the Student Manual with your student. His/her classroom teacher or building administrator will also discuss this document at school.\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp style=\\u0022margin:
```

now i need these values

here how to get these values

```
utID

showUserUndertaking

htmlDecription
```

here I am getting the same above postman response in

```
if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Received JSON data: \(jsonString)")    
}
```

**but not getting inside**

```
   print("errorCode: \(response.errorCode)")
   print("status: \(response.status)")
```

**code:**

```swift
func termsandCondition() {
    let baseURL = APIConstants.basePath
    let urlStr = "Undertaking?"
    var strKey    = String()
    strKey       += strKey.keyPath()
    
    let key = "key=\(strKey)"
    
    let SchCode = "&SchCode=\(strSchoolCodeSender)"
    let UserID = "&UserID=\(intUserID.toString)"//intUserID.toString
    let UserType = "&UserType=\(strPassword)"//intUserType.toString
    
    guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + urlStr + key + SchCode + UserID + UserType) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    print("the url is:......\(url)")
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
        
        if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Received JSON data: \(jsonString)")
            
        } else {
            print("Unable to decode JSON data")
        }
        
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try decoder.decode(UserUndertakingResponse.self, from: data)
            print("errorCode: \(response.errorCode)")
            print("status: \(response.status)")
            // Similarly, access other properties...
        } catch {
            print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")
        }
        
    }.resume()
}
```

error:

> Error decoding JSON....: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No string key for value in object around line 1, column 1." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around line 1, column 1., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=1})))

**EDIT:** this is the model

func termsandCondition() {
let baseURL = APIConstants.basePath
let urlStr = "User/UserUndertaking?"
var strKey    = String()
strKey       += strKey.keyPath()

```
let key = "key=\(strKey)"

let SchCode = "&SchCode=\(strSchoolCodeSender)"
let UserID = "&UserID=\(intUserID.toString)"//intUserID.toString
let UserType = "&UserType=\(intUserType)"//intUserType.toString

guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + urlStr + key + SchCode + UserID + UserType) else {
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}
print("the url is:......\(url)")

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        return
    }

    if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Received JSON data: \(jsonString)")
        
    } else {
        print("Unable to decode JSON data")
    }
    print("-------------------------------")
    print(data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())
    print("-------------------------------")
    
    let backendJsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    
    if let data = backendJsonStr?.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            // Deserialize the data into a JSON object
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                // Use the json dictionary here
                print("json response........ \(json)")
            } else {
                print("Failed to convert JSON string to dictionary.")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Failed to convert string to data.")
    }

}.resume()
```

}

error:

> Error deserializing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set. around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}

```swift
struct UserUndertakingResponse: Codable {
    let errorCode: Int
    let status: String
    let message: String
    let utID: String
    let showUserUndertaking: Bool
    let htmlDescription: String // This will hold the HTML content as a string
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case errorCode, status, message, utID, showUserUndertaking, htmlDescription
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your model -> UserUndertakingResponse.

Comment: Is `print("Received JSON data: \(jsonString)")` called? If yes, does it look like the JSON you get with POSTMAN? Is `print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")` called? If yes, what's the error? What is `UserUndertakingResponse`? Does the response from POSTMAN really start with a double quote? (I don't think so, but to be clear).

Comment: @HammerClass, added model in post edit section.. which i have tried

Comment: @Larme Is print("Received JSON data: \(jsonString)") called? If yes, does it look like the JSON you get with POSTMAN?-----> yes
Is print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)") called?----> yes.. i have added that error in my post edidt section.. yes post man response showing in bw "" same as in swagger as well please once take a look

Comment: Reading the error, I guess that really your response start with a double quote, which is wrong, and then not a valid JSON (since almost all other double quotes should be escaped). Could you check that? There are online JSON validator.

Comment: If the response it not valid JSON, either contact the server developer to send back real JSON, or if you can't, you can check if the first character (and/or last) is a Double quote and remove them.

Comment: Error clearly state Model is not getting matched with the JSON Response. 
Can you print the response from Postman because there is clearly issue with the JSON.

Comment: According to the error message the response is a nested JSON string. Trim the string by double quote – or more efficient remove the first and last `UInt8` byte from `data` – before decoding it. By the way the `URLRequest` is redundant for a GET request and it's highly recommended to build the URL more reliable with `URLComponents/URLQueryItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing the raw response, you have JSON Stringified, ie JSON String inside JSON.

So you need to decode first the JSON as it was a String, then decode according to your own model:

```
do {
    let string = try JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: data)
    let object = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserUndertakingResponse.self, from: Data(string.utf8))
    print(object)
} catch {
    print("Error decoding JSON: \(error)")

}
```

Your response has a typo, either it's fixed on the API, or you can force the decoding:
It's written "htmlDecription" instead of "htmlDescription" (missing an "s").

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case errorCode, status, message, utID, showUserUndertaking
    case htmlDescription = "htmlDecription"
}
```

Now, unrelated to your issue, but name your variables starting with a lowercase:

```
let SchCode = "&SchCode=\(strSchoolCodeSender)"
```

-->

```
let schCode = "&SchCode=\(strSchoolCodeSender)"
```

Also, for constructing the URL, I'd suggest to use `URLQueryItem`:

```
let baseURL = APIConstants-basePath.com + "/Undertaking"
var components = URLComponents(string: baseURL)
components?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "SchCode", value: strSchoolCodeSender),
                          URLQueryItem(name: "UserID", value: intUserID.toString)
                          ...
    ]
guard let url = components.url else { 
    print("Invalid URL")
    return
}
```

Comment: The API developer could fix the typo in *htmlDecription* at the same time 

Comment: Haha, indeed. I didn't even read the whole JSON sample ^^

Comment: updated the error in post for this answer.. please guide me

Comment: JSON seems to be invalid. I don't know why since you don't share the FULL JSON and what you really receive with `URLSession`. Could you share `print(data.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined())`?

Comment: got something like this
227b5c226572726f72436f64655c223a302c5c227374617475735c223a5c22737563636573735c222c5c226d6573736167655c223a5c225573657220556e64657274616b696e675c222c5c22757449445c223a5c22663657315844497a44326c6d4e4c38........sooooooon

Comment: Oh, you have "5c", so it backslash. So it's really a correctly escaped JSON...
So it should let's forget about the `cleanData` and just do `let string = try JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: data); let response = try decoder.decode(UserUndertakingResponse.self, from: Data(string))`

Comment: I just noticed that the backslash was indeed in your response, but since you used Quotation instead of Code tags, it was hidden, It's present in the raw value (by doing Edit, we see it).

Comment: i used your edited code then got this
Error decoding JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "htmlDescription", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"htmlDescription\", intValue: nil) (\"htmlDescription\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: can we use JSONSerialization to convert string to json object?... i have tried but still error.. please take a look at my post edit section

Comment: Now it's starting to debug correctly, it's just that you have a decoding error. And it's linked to the first comment  from Vadian. Your JSON doesn't have `htmlDescription`, it has `htmlDecription`.

Comment: oh yeah got it. now what should i do.. when i ask to backend developer he said we need to show paragraphs and hyper links and spaces so they are sending it in string formate

Comment: Does it work now? What's your question? It's strange to send JSON Stringified, but it's fine.

Comment: noo still not getting response yet.. please help
in your edited code got this error

Comment: Error decoding JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "htmlDescription", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"htmlDescription\", intValue: nil) (\"htmlDescription\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: @Swift Please read the very first comment, there is a key-typo, a missing `s`. Change the CodingKey `htmlDescription = htmlDecription`

Comment: @vadian that is coming from backend `htmlDecription ` so how can i change

Comment: Please read Larme's edited answer carefully.

Comment: @Larme, could you please take a look at this post as well got stuck from long.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78227538/response-not-coming-from-alamofire-post-method-servicecall-in-swift