# Response not coming from Alamofire post method servicecall in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

when i give same parameters i am getting response in postman like this

[image]

**code:** why i am not getting response like postman in this makeMultipartRequest() call? where am i wrong? how to get response and error while parsing.

```swift
func makeMultipartRequest() {
    let url = "https://test.com/SaveUndertakingAckowledgement"
    
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "SchCode": "Test",
        "key": "ndjsfnjkds==",
        "UserID": 11,
        "UserType": 3,
        "UtID": "kfnksdlnfks"
    ]
    
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let data = "\(value)".data(using: .utf8) {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, to: url) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    print("Response JSON: \(value)")
                    // Handle success response
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    // Handle error
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
            // Handle error
        }
    }
}

func makePostRequest() {
    let url = "https://test.com/SaveUndertakingAckowledgement"
    
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "SchCode": "test",
        "key": "nsjdkfn--=",
        "UserID": 11,
        "UserType": 3,
        "UtID": "ewiw/D264"
    ]
    
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Response JSON only post...: \(value)")
                // Handle success response
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error only post...: \(error)")
                // Handle error
            }
        }
}
```

Response JSON:

```json
{
    Message = "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://gfvhv.test.com/SaveUndertakingAckowledgement'.";
    MessageDetail = "No action was found on the controller 'User' that matches the request.";
}
```

Comment: In postman, you appear to be including `SchCode`, `key`, `UserID`, `UserType`, and `UtID` as parameters to the request URL, not in the body of a multipart request. Request parameters and a body of a `POST` are two different things. And you don’t even share with us what is in the body of the Postman `POST` request, so we cannot comment about that.

Comment: @Rob, as a multipart or normal also got same response in console.. just i have edited with makePostRequest() call in post both the ways got same.... i dont add anything in the body of postman... i just pasted swagger api in postman so it gives like that

Comment: @Rob, actually i got in swagger there if i add all parameters it gives response.. apart from swagger i dont have any other documet

Comment: @Rob... curl -X POST "http://test.com/api/User/SaveUndertakingAckowledgement?SchCode=test&key=vxcvxc13dfdfsfsddsfsdf&UserID=11&UserType=3&UtID=skfnsklfnlsnfla" -H "accept: application/json"

Comment: The `makePostRequest` seems like a more promising alternative, but it looks like that even with an `encoding` of `URLEncoding.default`, Alamofire puts the parameters in the body of the request, not the URL. (This is somewhat understanding, as `POST` requests almost always put the payload in the body of the request, not the URL. This is a good practice because URLs can be leaked, whereas the body is protected by https.) Are you able to refactor your endpoint to support this payload in the body (typically an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request; a multipart request if you must)?

Comment: You shouldn't do a multipart form data if in Postman it's not doing it. Just do a simple POST. The Params being at the same time in the URL and the Body is strange. Ask Postman to generate a cURL (or your doc swagger) and ask Alamofire to generate one too (with a simple POST method, not a multiform one). Compare and work to make it the same... You can generate Swift code with Postman (not beautiful one), share it and let us compare the two codes...

Comment: As an aside, diagnostic tools like Wireshark and Charles Proxy are really useful in intercepting requests so you can compare and contrast the curl attempts with the Alamofire attempts. Yes, the first time you use one of these tools, it's a bit of a heavy lift to gain proficiency, but once you master one or the other, it makes debugging this sort of stuff much easier. It's a great skill/tool to master.

Comment: Does your Swagger has a cURL generate code? If yes, test it in `Terminal.app`. If then it works, please share it with us (and obfuscate any private values), at least we can work from there.

Comment: FWIW, another reason to refactor the endpoint to accept the parameters in the body, rather than the URL, is that there are constraints as to how long a URL can be (2kb, IIRC), whereas you have much greater flexibility when the payload is in the body of the request.

Comment: I don't know what the backend is using, but it's generally very simple change to accept parameters in the body of the request. E.g., in PHP, use `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` rather than `$_GET`…

Comment: @Rob, my bad I didn't know that Postman would add the params if you add them manually in the query for a POST. I thought OP was adding in both places. Regarding AlamoFire, it's `AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: ...)`, you can specify the `destination`  for the parameters and force them into the URL even if it's not common at all.

Comment: @Larme – Yep, that `URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)`, instead of `URLEncoding.default`, in the OP’s `makePostRequest` implementation should do it. I still contend that the backend should be changed to permit it in the body of the request, but that gets around the immediate problem. Good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78228080/1271826). +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your Postman screen, you need do a "simple" POST (no multiform part) and put the parameters in the URL (while for a POST it's usually in the `httpBody`).

The Alamofire solution would be then:

```
AF.request(url,
           method: .post,
           parameters: parameters,
           encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString),
           headers: nil)  //Put your headers there
```

With `URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)` you should be able to tell to put the parameters inside the URL (ie as the query).

Side note:
You can generate `cURL` with POSTMAN, and you can generate `cURL` with Alamofire. It's can be really helpful to have a common ground for comparison and trying to match the working solution.

In Alamofire, you just need:

```
Alamofire.request(...)
         .cURLDescription { 
             print("AF cURL generated:\($0)")
         }
         .response(...) //or .responseJSON(), but it's deprecated, prefers other ones
```

In your case, I got:

```
$ curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8" \
    -H "User-Agent: ... Alamofire/5.4.0" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
    "https://test.com/SaveUndertakingAckowledgement?SchCode=Test&UserID=11&UserType=3&UtID=kfnksdlnfks&key=ndjsfnjkds%3D%3D"
```

Except for the User-Agents, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding which are more specific to the app/device and are usually not problematic, we see that the parameters have been added to the URL.

Comment: Side note 2: I just saw you accepted Rob answer on another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/78143285/1801544 I reminded too, but use Postman to generate cURL or Swift code to help compare (try the cURL in Terminal or Swift code in app just to be sure it's working). It's often better than a Postman screenshot.

Comment: thank you.. actually my office gave me existing project with their complex code which i really dont understand. so in these initial days i was panic. what i know also unable to use.